# not able to login with my new password after changing it (password hashed)

Tags: hash, change-password

i have hashed my password during registration and also able to log in with the hashed password. i also have implemented a change password page wherein it asks for the old password then you can change it if it matches the old password.  I am able to change it however afterwards, its not letting me to log in. here is my change password aspx.cs code:

```
string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    string str = null;
    SqlCommand com;
    byte up;
    protected void btn_update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conn);
        con.Open();
        str = "select * from UserData ";
        com = new SqlCommand(str, con);
        SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (BusinessLayer.ShoppingCart.CreateSHAHash(txt_cpassword.Text) == reader["Password"].ToString())
            {
                up = 1;
            }
        }
        reader.Close();
        con.Close();
        if (up == 1)
        {
            con.Open();
            str = "update UserData set Password=@Password where UserName='" + Session["New"].ToString() + "'";
            com = new SqlCommand(str, con);
            com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Password", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50));
            com.Parameters["@Password"].Value = BusinessLayer.ShoppingCart.CreateSHAHash(txt_npassword.Text);
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            lbl_msg.Text = "Password changed Successfully";
        }
        else
        {
            lbl_msg.Text = "Please enter correct Current password";
        }
    }
```

in the database, it still shows the hashed password but its not letting me log in. i am successful from registration to login w/ the hashed password but this time, when password has been changed, its not recognizing the new password. what am i missing here? thanks! btw here is my hashed code in the businesslayer:

```
public static string CreateSHAHash(string Phrase)
    {
        SHA512Managed HashTool = new SHA512Managed();
        Byte[] PhraseAsByte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string.Concat(Phrase));
        Byte[] EncryptedBytes = HashTool.ComputeHash(PhraseAsByte);
        HashTool.Clear();
        return Convert.ToBase64String(EncryptedBytes);
    }
```

here is the code for login:

```
 protected void btn_Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();
        string checkuser = "select count(*) from UserData where Username = '" + txtUser.Text + "'";
        SqlCommand scm = new SqlCommand(checkuser, conn);
        int temp = Convert.ToInt32(scm.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
        conn.Close();
        if (temp == 1)
        {
            conn.Open();
            string checkPassword = "select Password from UserData where Username ='" + txtUser.Text + "'";
            SqlCommand passCom = new SqlCommand(checkPassword, conn);
            string password = passCom.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            if (password == BusinessLayer.ShoppingCart.CreateSHAHash(txtPassword.Text))
            {
                Session["New"] = txtUser.Text;
                Response.Write("<script>alert('Logged In')</script>");
                Response.Redirect("OrderNow.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                lblcrederror.Text = ("Credentials dont match");
            }

        }
        else
        {
            lblcrederror.Text = ("Credentials dont match");
        }
    }
```

Comment: where is the code for login? Also, please tag the question by product too so that it's helpful for the reviewers and you get the appropriate answers

Comment: prevent sql injections by not concatenating user inputs with sql statement. Did you debug and see if both the hash values are correct, i.e. from the DB and the one generated from user entered password?

Comment: yes i am able to log in with the given code above. knowing that the passowrd registered is hashed on the DB

Comment: After the password change is the new hash being stored in the database properly? I also noticed upon button click you are querying for "select * from UserData" which is whole table and not just logged on user. Is that correct?

Comment: yes password hash is stored correctly after password change @Nimesh

Comment: In your question, what do you mean by _its not recognizing the new password_ ? Are you again redirecting the user to login or directly sending the user to homepage? I don't see any of the option after message **Password changed Successfully**. If you want to redirect the user, there should be `response.redirect` statement, similar to the one present in login page.

Comment: after i updated the password and try to log in, its giving the incorrect credentials error. @Nimesh am i missing or lacking a code on why its not recognizing the updated password?

Comment: Code looks okay to me. Did you debug and see where is it failing? on the password comparison line or on `temp==1` line? Since both the messages are same you won't come to know where the issue is.

Comment: @Nimesh still not successful with this. no errors